# Nginx: Issue serving static assets (js, css, etc.) with multi locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

For demonstrating purposes, I have a very basic app setup. It consists of **two** projects, **app01** and **app02**
Both folders are int the **apps** folder

```
apps
├── app01
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── style.css
│   └── subpage
│       └── index.html
└── app02
    ├── index.html
    └── style.css
```

The actual alias works. When I go to `my-apps.local:3460` I see `Welcome to App 01` and when I go to `my-apps.local:3460/blog` I see `Welcome to App 02 (Blog)`
However the CSS (or any other static file) is not loaded in my `/blog` location.

In my Nginx conf file for this project I have also set up very basic:

```
listen      *:3460;
server_name example.com;

location ~* ^/blog2 {
  alias /Users/username/test/apps/app2/;
  try_files $uri index.html =404;
  index index.html;
}

location /blog1 {
  alias /Users/username/test/apps/app1/;
  try_files $uri index.html =404;
  index index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location /blog1 {
  alias /example.com/apps/app01;
}  

location /blog2 {
  alias /example.com/apps/app02;
}
```

**apps/app01/index.html**

Your HTML files must use relative links for all URIs.  Absolute URIs will point to the root of your server, which would bypass the "/blog1" interception

`https://example.com/blog1/`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Welcome to 01
```

**apps/app01/subpage/index.html**

For subpages, maintain the use of relative links, but define the relative path root with the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag.

`https://example.com/blog1/subpage/`

```html
<base href="/blog1/"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Welcome to subpage 01
```

Alternatively, you could omit `<base>` and maintain parent `../` folder locations, which become cumbersome when files are moved.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
```